# Attach a form input to a node that will be submitted by multiple users

Tags: forms, webforms

I'm trying to create a content type that serves as a "Contest". Each contest needs the ability to upload an image by the user. Basically, I'm looking for the best way to attach a form field (file upload) to each Contest and be able to monitor all submissions, and by a user basis, for each individual contest, separately.

I've looked into Webform and Entityforms, but kind of running into road blocks. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module. or

Try the [Simple Contest](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_contest) module

> Simple Contest module provides contest system for Drupal websites.
>
> Features:
>
> - contests are nodes. multiple contests of multiple contest type can be    run same time
> - Two winner types : Users & Node, that means winners can be "user" or    node"
> - multiple winners can be chosen by ranking/weight
> - Supports both automatic and manual winners selection
> - Winner chosen rule will be based on View. so it is up to you to    decide how the winner will be selected
> - Modules integration with Views, Token, Rules, Userpoints, Date    Repeat, Commerce Coupon, UC Gift Certificate & UC Coupon
> - Token integration and customized E-mail notifications

Please note the this module is in dev version. So try that in local (test) environment.